# Selecionar datas baseado na soma total de determinada coluna

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel

Boa noite. Baseado no cadastro de exemplo em anexo, eu teria que selecionar todas as datas que são iguais e estão no mesmo restaurante e que a soma da quantidade seja > 10, pois preciso desabilitar essas datas do meu datepicker.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Fala Marlon,

Acredito que precisa de algo assim:

```sql
SELECT 
    t.restaurante,
    SUM(t.quantidade) AS quantidade,
    t.dataReserva
FROM
    teste t
WHERE 
    t.dataReserva >= NOW()
GROUP BY t.dataReserva, t.restaurante;
```

Laravel

```php
$reservas = teste::select("restaurante", DB::raw("SUM(t.quantidade) AS quantidade"), "dataReserva")
->where("dataReserva", ">=", date("Y-m-d"))
->groupBy("dataReserva", "restaurante");
```

Comment: Valeu demais Thiago. Funcionou perfeitamente!